# Why doesn't find/rm -iname '*phpmyadmin' delete phpMyAdmin-Version-XYZ.zip?

Tags: find, rm

I have this following code:

```
find ./ -iname '*phpmyadmin' -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

It deletes a dir called `phpmyadmin`, but it **does not** delete a file called `phpMyAdmin-Version-XYZ.zip`

Even if I remove the `-rf`, it still won't delete it (probably because a second problem with the -iname not affecting case insensitivity).

1. Is there a way to delete any inode in a single rm (file, dir, softlink)?
2. Why does adding the `-iname` not have an effect?

Note: I didn't find a "delete any inode" argument in `man rm`.

Comment: If your `find` supports it, try the `-delete` action.  (Also, see https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Deleting-Files.html#Deleting-Files for extensive discussion of the many ways to do this incorrectly.)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The problem is that you are matching a file that ends in `phpmyadmin` (*case-insensitively*) by using the pattern `*phpmyadmin`. To get any file that contains the string `phpmyadmin` (case-insensitively), use `-iname '*phpmyadmin*'`:

```
find ./ -iname '*phpmyadmin*' -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Perhaps getting the matched files before removal would be sane:

```
find ./ -iname '*phpmyadmin*'
```

To answer your first question, there is no option in `rm` in userspace to deal with inodes.

Comment: Quite possibly should consider `-depth` so that `find` doesn't try to recurse into a directory it's just deleted.

Comment: Not to take anything away from the answer, which does include this, but just wanted to emphasise that the reason that the OP's command did not _delete_ the zip file was that it didn't *find* it, due to the lack of the trailing '*' on the pattern.

Comment: @GwynEvans That also means than OP didn't test the `find` before adding the `-exec` parameter. Very dangerous.

Comment: Might suggest `-exec rm -rf {} +` -- no point to the performance penalty of running one `rm` per file.

Answer (score 2):

```
find ./ -iname '*phpmyadmin*' -exec /usr/lib/klibc/bin/nuke {} +
```

This works even if somebody creates a -phpmyadmin directory.

Comment: Find (at least here) prefixes the names with `./`, so that's not needed: it'd execute `rm -rf ./-phpmyadmin`, which should work with any sane `rm`. Try `find ./ -iname '*whatever*' -exec echo '{}' ';'` to test

Comment: @derobert: I've had it screw up on a handful of occasions. Once bitten, twice shy. Maybe it can only happen if the argument to find is something like '-annoyingdirectoryname'.

Comment: If someone ran, say, `find */` instead of `find .`, that would do it (if a matching directory name started with a dash). That said, I'd tend to suggest using `--` to handle such cases by providing an explicit end-of-options *before* the `{}` argument. (See #10 in [POSIX utility syntax guidelines](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html#tag_12_02)).

Comment: As an aside -- `{} +` is considerably more efficient than `{} \;`, as it'll run only as many instances of your command (`nuke` in this case) as necessary to fit all items found on the command line, as opposed to one-per-each.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy If they ran `find */` then the problem wouldn't happen in `-exec`, the directory with a hyphen would appear to be a `find` option and it would complain.

Comment: Good point. I'm... very curious... how @Joshua got the behavior they claim to have seen. Perhaps if they were using `xargs` to process `find`'s output, then? A file named `foo -bar` would do it with a `find | xargs` pipeline, if not using `find -print0` and `xargs -0`.

Comment: Probably a broken find. I learned on a system with a lot of broken tools.